# How do I disable the security certificate check in cloudscraper Python

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to use cloudscraper to bypass some webistes cloudflare waf , it's works well but , i'm tring to disable disable the security certificate check using `verify=False` as shown in code below but it's throw an error

error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x:\documents\python\django_projects\storage\saver\image_save.py", line 49, in fetch
    response  = session.request(method=method,url=url,headers=headers,params=params,timeout=timeout,verify=False)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cloudscraper\__init__.py", line 257, in request
    self.perform_request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cloudscraper\__init__.py", line 190, in perform_request 
    return super(CloudScraper, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen        
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request  
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 398, in connect
    context.verify_mode = resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 738, in verify_mode
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).verify_mode.__set__(self, value)
ValueError: Cannot set verify_mode to CERT_NONE when check_hostname is enabled.
```

code

````
import cloudscraper
from urllib.parse import urlparse

session = cloudscraper.CloudScraper(
            browser={
            'browser': 'chrome',
            'platform': 'windows',
            'mobile': False
                    },)
def fetch(url : str , method : str = "GET",refer : str = None,params : dict = {},
          timeout : int = 40) -> bytes:
    
    url_r  = urlparse(url)
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36',
        'referer': refer if refer else "%s://%s/"%(url_r.scheme,url_r.netloc)}
    try:
        response  = session.request(method=method,url=url,headers=headers,params=params,timeout=timeout,verify=False)
        return response.content 
    except  Exception as e:   print(e) ```
````

Answer (score 2):

i was able to solve it
using this

```
import cloudscraper

import ssl


session = cloudscraper.CloudScraper(
            browser={
            'browser': 'chrome',
            'platform': 'windows',
            'mobile': False
                    },ssl_context=ssl._create_unverified_context()
)
```

Comment: Not checking remote certificate is removing all usefulness out of TLS, and you might as well just use HTTP.

Comment: some cases when i bind domain to origin ip it throws ssl errors  and the only way to bypass that problem is to not verify ssl , i been doing that with curl -k before

Comment: Then just use HTTP. You are loosing all benefits of HTTPS. Better to have clearly no security than the feeling of security, that is just not there.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek i use it to scrap some websites and i don't really need ssl , in fact when i disabled ssl verification script somehow become faster

Comment: " and i don't really need ssl " You don't control that, and obviously things do no work like you seem to think they do. If you use an `https://` URL then you are doing TLS (SSL is dead since 20+ years). "in fact when i disabled ssl verification script somehow become faster " Yeah if you remove speed limits on roads, you can drive at 250kmh, and so? Anyway, it is certainly not the certificate check that takes time (as it happens only once at beginning of TLS handshake so minor impact on the whole session).